# Ubuntu 13.04 network access

Tags: networking, 13.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 9.10 to 13.04.  As soon as I logged in, the system announced I was no longer connected to the network, and I can't figure out how to connect.  I'm using an ethernet cable, so there's no wireless stuff to deal with - and it had no trouble connecting the whole time it was upgrading.  Does anyone know how to turn the network connection back on?

Comment: This usually has to do with incorrect configuration in your /etc/network/interfaces. Try commenting everything except "lo" (local) interface on the first line.

Comment: I tried that, thought there's only one line other than "auto lo", but I don't have permissions to change it, although I should have admin privileges.  I don't know how to get to a console in Ubuntu to try it.

Comment: I made the change, so the only un-commented line in the file is now "auto lo".  It no longer says it's disconnecting from the network, but neither is it connecting.

Comment: How do you deduce that the network is down? Did you try "ping localhost"? If you want to set static-ip for the ethernet adapter, then try configuring that in the /etc/network/interfaces and check. But usually, the network-manager should take care of this for you.